# SQL Schema for XBRL Document storage

Tags: mysql, database-design

Does anybody know of a relational database schema that can be used to store XBRL data? I am looking to store financial report data (balance sheet, income statement and profit/loss statement data) along with other company data (Name, Stock Ticker, etc.) in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't any db supporting the XML sections of SQL2003 work?  If you are trying to store the document as reported, I think you'd want to store as an XML file, not breaking it apart.

So I think if you are storing these as records of documents, your schema is not going to be based on XBRL but rather based on simple document management.